# Errors trying to build the Sygic integrated xamrin example using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: android, visual-studio-2017, sygic

I have followed the Readme.Txt file associated with the sample IntegXamarinDemo3D using Visual Studio 2017.  In fact I have done it several times with the same results.

When I try to compile I get errors from:

- Com.Vividsolutions.Jts.Geom.Impl.PackedCoordinateSequence.cs
- Com.Vividsolutions.Jts.Geomgraph.Edge.cs

These errors prevent SygicLibBinding from building and that leads to errors when trying to build the sample application.

The errors detail is:

Error   CS0507  'Edge.ComputeIM(IntersectionMatrix)': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member 'GraphComponent.ComputeIM(IntersectionMatrix)'    SygicLibBinding C:\Carputer-Android-Embedded\Source\CAESygicApp\SygicLibBinding\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Vividsolutions.Jts.Geomgraph.Edge.cs    570 Active

Error   CS0507  'PackedCoordinateSequence.Double.GetCoordinateInternal(int)': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member 'PackedCoordinateSequence.GetCoordinateInternal(int)' SygicLibBinding C:\Carputer-Android-Embedded\Source\CAESygicApp\SygicLibBinding\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Vividsolutions.Jts.Geom.Impl.PackedCoordinateSequence.cs    283 Active

Error   CS0507  'PackedCoordinateSequence.Float.GetCoordinateInternal(int)': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member 'PackedCoordinateSequence.GetCoordinateInternal(int)'  SygicLibBinding C:\Carputer-Android-Embedded\Source\CAESygicApp\SygicLibBinding\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Vividsolutions.Jts.Geom.Impl.PackedCoordinateSequence.cs    617 Active

Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'PolygonizeGraph' does not exist in the namespace 'Com.Vividsolutions.Jts.Operation.Polygonize' (are you missing an assembly reference?) SygicLibBinding C:\Carputer-Android-Embedded\Source\CAESygicApp\SygicLibBinding\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Vividsolutions.Jts.Operation.Polygonize.Polygonizer.cs  16  Active

Error   CS0534  'Edge' does not implement inherited abstract member 'GraphComponent.IsIsolated.get' SygicLibBinding C:\Carputer-Android-Embedded\Source\CAESygicApp\SygicLibBinding\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Vividsolutions.Jts.Geomgraph.Edge.cs    10  Active

Frankly, I have no idea what the errors mean and I probably shouldn't have to.

Are this sample and the readme incompatible with Visual Studio 2017 or is there a newer SDK?  The one I have just downloaded is:

- TRUCK3D_ANDROID_Integrated

Backing down to VS 2015 is no an option and my project is on hold until I can resolve this.

Any and all help appreciated.

Regards,
Jim

Answer (score 0):

try to add these lines to SygicLibBinding/Transforms/Metadata.xml file:

```
<metadata>
  ...
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.prep']/class[@name='PreparedPolygon']" />
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.prep']/class[@name='PreparedPoint']" />
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.prep']/class[@name='PreparedLineString']" />
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.vividsolutions.jts.operation.polygonize']/class[@name='Polygonizer']" />
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.vividsolutions.jts.simplify']/class[@name='TaggedLineStringSimplifier']" />
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.impl']/class[@name='PackedCoordinateSequence']" />
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.vividsolutions.jts.geomgraph']/class[@name='Edge']" />  
</metadata>
```

However, it seems that you are using older version of SygicLib. Feel free to contact Sygic support team to get the latest version with working demo.

Lukas (Sygic)

Answer (score 0):

Lukas (Sygic),

I tried as you suggested, added to the lines to the Metadata and downloaded the SDK you linked to (which was what I had) and when I compiled I am left with these errors:

Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Callback' does not exist in the namespace 'Com.Sygic.Sdk.Api' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  CAESygicApp C:\Carputer-Android-Embedded\Source\CAESygicApp\CAESygicApp\MainActivity.cs 10

Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'OnSearchListener' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  CAESygicApp C:\Carputer-Android-Embedded\Source\CAESygicApp\CAESygicApp\MainActivity.cs 84

Error   CS0115  'SearchListener.OnResult(string, IList, int)': no suitable method found to override   CAESygicApp C:\Carputer-Android-Embedded\Source\CAESygicApp\CAESygicApp\MainActivity.cs 88

Error   CS0117  'ApiLocation' does not contain a definition for 'SearchLocation'    CAESygicApp C:\Carputer-Android-Embedded\Source\CAESygicApp\CAESygicApp\MainActivity.cs 52

Error   CS0103  The name 'RcOk' does not exist in the current context   CAESygicApp C:\Carputer-Android-Embedded\Source\CAESygicApp\CAESygicApp\MainActivity.cs 89

I have searched the Object Browser for the SygicLibBindings and do not find

```
Com.Sygic.Sdk.Api.Callback;
```

Nor do I find OnSearchListener in any of the code.

What am I missing?

Jim